# Cats: Non tail recursive tailRecM method for Monads

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, scala-cats

In [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats), when a  Monad is created using `Monad` trait, an implementation for method `tailRecM` should be provided.

I have a scenario below that I found impossible to provide a tail recursive implementation of `tailRecM`

```
  sealed trait Tree[+A]

  final case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

  final case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]

  implicit val treeMonad = new Monad[Tree] {

    override def pure[A](value: A): Tree[A] = Leaf(value)

    override def flatMap[A, B](initial: Tree[A])(func: A => Tree[B]): Tree[B] =
      initial match {
        case Branch(l, r) => Branch(flatMap(l)(func), flatMap(r)(func))
        case Leaf(value) => func(value)
      }

    //@tailrec
    override def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(func: (A) => Tree[Either[A, B]]): Tree[B] = {
      func(a) match {
        case Branch(l, r) =>
          Branch(
            flatMap(l) {
              case Right(l) => pure(l)
              case Left(l) => tailRecM(l)(func)
            },
            flatMap(r){
              case Right(r) => pure(r)
              case Left(r) => tailRecM(r)(func)
            }
          )

        case Leaf(Left(value)) => tailRecM(value)(func)

        case Leaf(Right(value)) => Leaf(value)
      }
    }
  }
```

1) According to the above example, how this `tailRecM` method can be used for optimizing `flatMap` method call? Does the implementation of the `flatMap` method is overridden/modified by `tailRecM` at the compile time ?

2) If the `tailRecM` is not tail recursive as above, will it still be efficient than using the original `flatMap` method ?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Relation between `tailRecM` and `flatMap`

To answer you first question, the following code is part of [FlatMapLaws.scala](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/laws/src/main/scala/cats/laws/FlatMapLaws.scala), from [cats-laws](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/lawtesting.html). It tests consistency between `flatMap` and `tailRecM` methods.

```
/**
 * It is possible to implement flatMap from tailRecM and map
 * and it should agree with the flatMap implementation.
 */
def flatMapFromTailRecMConsistency[A, B](fa: F[A], fn: A => F[B]): IsEq[F[B]] = {
  val tailRecMFlatMap = F.tailRecM[Option[A], B](Option.empty[A]) {
    case None => F.map(fa) { a => Left(Some(a)) }
    case Some(a) => F.map(fn(a)) { b => Right(b) }
  }

  F.flatMap(fa)(fn) <-> tailRecMFlatMap
}
```

This shows how to implement a `flatMap` from `tailRecM` and implicitly suggests that the compiler will not do such thing automatically. It's up to the user of the Monad to decide when it makes sense to use `tailRecM` over `flatMap`.

[This blog](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/tail-recursive-monads.html) has nice scala examples to explain when `tailRecM` comes in useful. It follows the [PureScript article](http://functorial.com/stack-safety-for-free/index.pdf) by Phil Freeman, which originally introduced the method.

It explains the downsides in using `flatMap` for *monadic composition*:

> This characteristic of Scala limits the usefulness of monadic composition where flatMap can call monadic function f, which then can call flatMap etc..

In contrast with a `tailRecM`-based implementation:

> This guarantees greater safety on the user of FlatMap typeclass, but it would mean that each the implementers of the instances would need to provide a safe tailRecM.

Many of the provided methods in cats leverage monadic composition. So, even if you don't use it directly, implementing `tailRecM` allows for more efficient composition with other monads.

### Implmentation for tree

In a different answer, @nazarii-bardiuk provides an implementation of `tailRecM` which is tail recursive, but does not pass the flatMap/tailRecM consistency test mentioned above. The tree structure is not properly rebuilt after recursion. A fixed version below:

```
def tailRecM[A, B](arg: A)(func: A => Tree[Either[A, B]]): Tree[B] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(toVisit: List[Tree[Either[A, B]]], 
           toCollect: List[Option[Tree[B]]]): List[Tree[B]] =
    toVisit match {
      case Branch(l, r) :: next =>
        loop(l :: r :: next, None :: toCollect)

      case Leaf(Left(value)) :: next =>
        loop(func(value) :: next, toCollect)

      case Leaf(Right(value)) :: next =>
        loop(next, Some(pure(value)) :: toCollect)

      case Nil =>
        toCollect.foldLeft(Nil: List[Tree[B]]) { (acc, maybeTree) =>
          maybeTree.map(_ :: acc).getOrElse {
            val left :: right :: tail = acc
            branch(left, right) :: tail
          }
        }
    }

  loop(List(func(arg)), Nil).head
}
```

([gist with test](https://gist.github.com/hjmeijer/587e613203620ee376a11e21990a211d))

You're probably aware, but your example (as well as the answer by @nazarii-bardiuk) is used in the book [Scala with Cats](https://underscore.io/books/scala-with-cats/) by Noel Welsh and Dave Gurnell (highly recommended).

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes there is a way to replace a call stack with explicit list.

Here `toVisit` keeps track of branches that are waiting to be processed.

And `toCollect` keeps branches that are waiting to be merged until corresponding branch is finished processed.

```
override def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: (A) => Tree[Either[A, B]]): Tree[B] = {
  @tailrec
  def go(toVisit: List[Tree[Either[A, B]]],
         toCollect: List[Tree[B]]): List[Tree[B]] = toVisit match {
    case (tree :: tail) =>
      tree match {
        case Branch(l, r) =>
          l match {
            case Branch(_, _) => go(l :: r :: tail, toCollect)
            case Leaf(Left(a)) => go(f(a) :: r :: tail, toCollect)
            case Leaf(Right(b)) => go(r :: tail, pure(b) +: toCollect)
          }
        case Leaf(Left(a)) => go(f(a) :: tail, toCollect)
        case Leaf(Right(b)) =>
          go(tail,
             if (toCollect.isEmpty) pure(b) +: toCollect
             else Branch(toCollect.head, pure(b)) :: toCollect.tail)
      }
    case Nil => toCollect
  }

  go(f(a) :: Nil, Nil).head
}
```

---

From [cats ticket](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/1329) why to use `tailRecM`

> tailRecM won't blow the stack (like almost every JVM program it may OOM), for any of the Monads in cats.

and then

> Without tailRecM (or recursive flatMap) being safe, libraries like
>   iteratee.io can't safely be written since they require monadic recursion.

and [another ticket](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/1278) states that clients of `cats.Monad` should be aware that some monads don't have stacksafe `tailRecM`

> tailRecM can still be used by those that are trying to get stack safety, so long as they understand that certain monads will not be able to give it to them

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I think you've answered my second question. Any idea about the first ?

Comment: @tharindu_DG added some links to cats tickets

Comment: @NazariiBardiuk looks like implementation is incorrect, it fails on a simple example:
`Branch(Branch(Leaf(31), Branch(Leaf(11), Leaf(2))), Leaf(12)).tailRecM[Tree, String](_.map(i => Right(i.toString))) shouldBe tree.map(_.toString)`